# Measure a power supply voltage with floating ground

Tags: power-supply, adc

I'd like to measure the output voltage on a power supply with a ADC and a micro-controller. The ADC is powered from a different source and the grounds of the power supplies are not connected. How can safely I measure the differential output voltage of the power supply? I'm sorry if this is a standard question, but I can't find a simple solution.

*Edit in response to the comments:*
The voltages I want to measure range between 0 and 14V. Precision is not important (a few percent). Frequency of measurements is low (about 1Hz). No high frequency components present.

Comment: What's the range of voltage that you are trying to measure? (From what value to what other value?) Would you be willing to consider anything other than using your ADC to make these measurements? How often will you be making the measurements? What precision is needed?

Comment: Also, are you expecting there to be any higher frequency (>100HZ) components to the voltage that you're measuring?

Comment: The voltages I want to measure range between 0 and 14V. Precision is not important (a few percent). Frequency of measurements about 1Hz. No high frequency components present.

Comment: you did not say that grounds had to be separate. ... use a battery to power the ADC and the μC, connect the ground between the PS and μC. use opto-couplers on any outputs from μC to outside world.

Comment: What digital interface (parallel bus, I2C, SPI, something else) does the ADC use to connect to the micro?

Comment: @hanno Can you consider a VCO? (You would get optoisolated pulses whose rate was dependent on the remote voltage measurement.) Precision, integral and differential nonlinearity, and other issues might still be a problem. But it makes it possible to use optos which are not intended for strictly linear operation. Regardless, I see an opto in your future?

Comment: @jonk I was thinking that too, but it's all for naught if the thing needs to be supplied from what he is measuring and it needs to go to zero... I'm thinking this is turning into an XY problem.

Comment: @Trevor Yes. But I have a feeling the OP doesn't really need to go smoothly all the way to 0. I don't see a reason in the explanation and it would be pretty unusual to actually need that capability. But what do I know?

Comment: you can get a cheap DMM with serial out (ex: ut61e), then a serial to uart adapter.

Comment: @dandavis That was my first thought too. But it raises the question, how does the DMM do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with the most hackish solution possible: Using an ESP8266 to stream the data wirelessly. It works.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If your grounds are guaranteed to be close, and the voltages are within the common mode range, a simple differential amplifier may be enough.

Otherwise, depending on the accuracy you need, your best bet is probably to use a linear opto-coupler circuit.

[image]

In your case the left side would be powered from the thing you are testing and the Vin would be some division of that voltage. However if the source goes below the supply requirements of U1, that will not work.